# Replace default chart in Pine Script while using overlay=true

Tags: charts, pine-script

Is it possible to replace/make invisible the default chart using Pine Script? As an example, the default chart always shows candles. I would like to write an indicator (using overlay=true) to erase (or make invisible) the default candle chart and replace it by just plotting the close values (e.g., plot(close)). This is just a simple example to illustrate what I want to do and where I'm getting stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's something I've needed in the past too, but unfortunately there's currently no Pine Script command available that allows for the manipulation of the visibility of the symbol on the chart.

It can be partially done, by making the body of the candle the same as the background color, but that still leaves the candle wicks and border intact.

```
barcolor(chart.bg_color)
```

Unfortunatly, there's no command to do the same for wickcolor and bordercolor.

Another approach could be to plot a new bar over the existing bars, with body, wicks and border all in the background color.
However, that will not work either - not even when you use `explicit_plot_zorder=true` - because the z-index of the chart symbol is always seems to be higher.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", explicit_plot_zorder=true, overlay=true)
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, "hideCandle", chart.bg_color, chart.bg_color, bordercolor=chart.bg_color)
```

So, in short, no solution for this yet.